# almost sure convergence conditional on the sample

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-convergence

I have the following problem (any help is really appreciated).

Given a sample of size $N$, I estimate a quantity (it does not matter what, but for the records it is a scalar, fixed coefficient), and I get an estimation error, which we may call $X_{N}$.

Defining $P^{\ast}$ as the probability conditional on the sample, I can show that

$P^{\ast}[|X_{N}|>\epsilon]=0$

almost surely, for all $\epsilon>0$. In other words, I can show that my estimator is a.s. consistent conditional on the sample.

Does this imply anything as far as unconditional convergence is concerned, i.e. can I say anything on $P[|X_{N}|>\epsilon]$, where $P$ denotes the probability "unconditional" on the sample? Under which conditions can I say that $P[|X_{N}|>\epsilon]=0$ as $N$ grows large?

Comment: Are you doing regression ? (i.e. given data $(X_1,Y_1),\ldots,(X_n,Y_n)$, building a regressor $g_n$ that has low error)

Comment: thanks - no no, not really - it is a different problem, I would think more akin to having a bootstrap estimator which converges a.s. conditional on the sample, and then I need to plug it in another estimator, and show that this other estimator converges to its true value, but I would prefer to avoid having to say that this estimator, too, converges conditional on the sample